# Puppeteer always complaining about chromium

Tags: npm, puppeteer

I was trying to run tests using Puppeteer(V2.0.0) and skipped chromium installation with `PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true`. So after `puppeteer` installation I cannot see `.local-chromium` folder under puppteer filder inside node module. I think that is expected.

So my expectation is to run against my local installed chrome (`79.0.3945.117`) which I have chromedriver locally and set the path withing the script as below

`this.browser = await puppeteerCommon.launch({
            headless: helper.headless,
            executablePath: "C:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe",`

But the problem is, when running the test still complaining with below error despite of no chromium installed

`TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to Chrome! The only Chrome revision guaranteed to work is r706915`

Can anyone shed some light here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppeteer doesn't need chromedriver. From [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions):

> **executablePath** Path to a Chromium or Chrome executable to run instead of the bundled Chromium. If executablePath is a relative path,
>   then it is resolved relative to current working directory.

Use a full path to `Chrome.exe` instead of chromedriver.

Comment: Thanks @mbit it's my bad not checking specifically whether it is `chrome` or `chromedriver.`